# Can't find SelectionMode option on toolkit ListPicker

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, wpftoolkit

I read everywhere that there is an option in the listpicker from the toolkit to have a multiple selection, but I can't find it. When I write

```
  <toolkit:ListPicker  x:Name="LP_MaritalStatus" Grid.Row="7" BorderThickness="2"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource IT_LP}" BorderBrush="White" SelectionMode="Multiple" ></toolkit:ListPicker>
```

I get SelectionMode="Multiple" underlined saying that this property doesn't exist.

I added the toolkit like this :

```
 xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

I added the toolkit with nuget, and I have my ListPicker get to work without the SelectionMode option. So did they remove it from the toolkit ? How can I get it back ?

Thank you

Comment: what version you are using

Comment: as @MuhammadSaifullah if you've got the correct version in it should be there. Take a look here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/f397b9/using-listpicker-in-windows-phone-7/

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a Option for `Multiple Selection`. you can set the

`ListPicker.SummaryForSelectedItems = MySelectedItemsString`

when you initialize the ListPicker. You can find sample over here [Multiple selection in Listpicker](http://attowares.com/blog/2011/09/25/multiple-selection-in-listpicker/) and also here in MSDN [C#.net sample code for multi selected Check Boxes and RadioButtons in Listpicker control in Windows Phone 8](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/bb6f05a8-dc5a-4f75-9613-293d4f6ab1a9/cnet-sample-code-for-multi-selected-check-boxes-and-radiobuttons-in-listpicker-control-in-windows?forum=wpdevelop)